# How to execute two different ResultSet Objects in the same method

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm running the JDBC with Oracle database, but when it come to execute queries on the same method it noes not execute the second.

```
public class PRACTICE_4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException{
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"hr","oracle");



        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT  e.first_name, e.last_name,d.department_name,l.city \n" + 
                                                            "FROM employees e\n" + 
                                                            "JOIN departments d\n" + 
                                                            "ON (e.department_id = d.department_id)\n" + 
                                                            "JOIN locations l\n" + 
                                                            "ON (d.location_id = l.location_id)"

                                                            + "WHERE l.city = ?"
                                                            + "AND e.employee_id = ?");

        PreparedStatement cities = con.prepareStatement("SELECT city FROM locations");

        try {
```

The first statement get successfully completed

```
            System.out.println("Please introduce one of the following cities:");
            ResultSet rs_cities = cities.executeQuery();

            while(rs_cities.next()) {System.out.print(rs_cities.getString("city") + " | ");}
            System.out.println();
            rs_cities.colse();
            statement.setString(1,"'" + scn.next() + "'");

            System.out.println("Please introduce a an employee ID");
            statement.setInt(2,scn.nextInt());
```

The second statement does not execute (print)

```
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
            String F_name = rs.getString("e.first_name");
            String L_name = rs.getString("e.last_name");
            String D_name = rs.getString("d.department_name");
            String C_name = rs.getString("l.city");

                System.out.println(F_name + "\t" + L_name  + "\t" + D_name  + "\t" + C_name );

            }

            rs.colse();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean `close();` instead of `colse();`.

Comment: As it stands, your code will not even compile (eg due to `rs.colse()` and `rs_cities.colse()`). Please post the actual code. If you're using Eclipse, the compilation error might also cause Eclipse to run your previous successfully compiled code. And if your code throws an exception, please make sure to post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Also did you note that `cities` is a simple statement that will read everything while `statement` is a more complex statement involving a lot lof inner joins that might cause it to have no result at all? The problem with `statement` might actually be this: `statement.setString(1,"'" + scn.next() + "'");` - if you call `setString()` you don't need to wrap the parameter in single quotes. Your code is adding single quotes to the value the query is looking for and I'd assume no city name will be wrapped in single quotes. Just `statement.setString(1, scn.next() );` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me check the below code.

Since u are using join with alias name  **String F_name = rs.getString("e.first_name");** should be  **String F_name = rs.getString("first_name");**

```
private void test() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<sid>";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "<username>", "<pass>");

    PreparedStatement request = con.prepareStatement("Select * from request where request_number = 101");
    PreparedStatement book = con.prepareStatement("Select * from book_store");

    ResultSet rs1 = request.executeQuery();
    while (rs1.next()) {
        System.out.println("Priting request result : " + rs1.getString("REQUEST_NUMBER") + ", " + rs1.getString("REQUEST_NAME"));
    }

    rs1.close();
    ResultSet rs2 = book.executeQuery();

    while (rs2.next()) {
        System.out.println("cities statement result : " + rs2.getString("SID") + ", " + rs2.getString("SNAME"));
    }

    rs2.close();

}
```

Result :

Priting request result : 101, Req987654321

Priting request result : 101, Testcheckforunittest

Priting request result : 101, Req_TestMobileApproval

Priting request result : 101, demo103

Priting request result : 101, test sec blank

Priting request result : 101, shreesh return test1 sup

cities statement result : 100, store1

cities statement result : 100, store1

cities statement result : 100, store1

cities statement result : 200, store2

cities statement result : 200, store2